# How to store versionable data in a database?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-design, mongoose, doctrine-orm

I want to implement some staging/versioning features in my upcoming web app.

Although I have mentioned the tags MySQL/Doctrine and MongoDB/Mongoose below, I'm actually not bound to one of these. These are just the ones I usually work with. I'll pick the technology which fits best.

Basically I want to allow my users to revert changes, save drafts (branch), publish changes (merge/commit) and so on. Pretty much the same like git does for code, I want this behavior for data.

I'm aware that such behavior heavily depends on application code, but first I need to find a suitable database schema.

While this would not be that hard with simple tables, I heavily struggle to find a good/clean solution when having tables with multiple relationships. Every approach I can think of either produces huge amounts redundant data or seem too complicated.

Imagine the following data, where every **Post** can have multiple **Tags**:

```
-- Create syntax for TABLE 'post'
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 'post_tag'
CREATE TABLE `post_tag` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 'tag'
CREATE TABLE `tag` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `label` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Duplicating the whole post and post_tag table on every change doesn't feel right. Especially because I'll end up with about another 5 related tables.

This is even worse when having OneToMany relationships with tables containing binary data or large strings. Duplicating them for no reason on every change would result in massive amounts of useless data.

But maybe it's the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Surely your `post` has more than an `id`??  (If so, edit to add an ellipsis or something.)

Toss the `Tag` table.  Toss `id` from `post_tag` and replace `tag_id` with `label`.  Here's a good schema for adding "tags" to "posts":

```
CREATE TABLE `post_tag` (
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (post_id, label),  -- also prevents duplicate entries
  INDEX(tag, post_id)            -- for going the other way
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

One of [*Rick's RoTs*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots):  "Normalize, but don't over-normalize."  Some more:  Use `UNSIGNED` and/or `NOT NULL` whenever appropriate.

The above only addresses "tagging".  If you want to discuss versioning, split off that as a separate question.  It is not nice to have two unrelated questions thrown together.  (Granted, "tagging" *may* be a tool for "versioning", but I think not.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately you got me wrong. Sorry if my question was unintelligible. The tags were just an example to illustrate a schema with ManyToMany relations. I actually wanted to ask for a good way to store changes to these relations. e.g a user edits a post and add or remove tags and then the admin can review/revert changes. Preferably creating some kind of snapshot on every "save" action, not only distinguishing by live/draft.

Comment: It is possible to see the schema used by Stackoverflow.com .  Note that it has a way to look at the edit history and to rollback changes.  Take a look at it.

Comment: Sounds great. Just found out stackexchange provides data dumps at archive.org. I'll have a look at these.